# SQL Server is pending with no response

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm writing a WinForms application. The application will manipulate the database. When I click one button, it does something to the database, and then the application jumps to another form. The problem is coming. Now if I do some query in SQL Server Management Studio in appointed table. The query will pending. I assume, maybe the application still has some connection with the table, for example, a transaction not closed. I am not sure. Do you know when SQL Server will have the pending problem?[image]

Comment: Can you post your code? it's a bit difficult for us to see what's going on otherwise.

Comment: Some code would be usefull..

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush  The problem is here. I don't know where is wrong in the code. I don't know which code section to paste here. It looks like some former interaction with the database has locked the table. So the next select query will be pending.

Comment: Have you checked the database to see what is blocking it? 
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2429/how-to-identify-blocking-in-sql-server-2005-and-2008/

Comment: GrandMasterFlush Thank you. Very useful.